# Android 14 webview onShowFileChooser callback keeps returning activity cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a file chooser in my Android webview application that seems to be broken on the Android 14 beta. After doing some digging, it seems like the file chooser always returns that the activity was cancelled, even if it was performed properly. This works fine on Android versions below 14. The file picker opens fine, I can select an image, and I am taken back to my application. But the code still reports that its cancelled.

Here is the Kotlin code handling this:

```kotlin
private var fileCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null
private val fileSelectorCallback =
    registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
      fileCallback?.let { cb ->
        fileCallback = null

        val data: Intent? = result.data
        // This always logs ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}
        Log.i("info data", result.toString())
        Log.i("info result code", "${result.resultCode} ${Activity.RESULT_OK}")
        val returnedValue: Array<Uri>? =
          if (result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            null
          } else if (data?.clipData != null) {
            // The files are in data.clipData if the user selected multiple files
            // https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15341
            val clipData = data.clipData!!

            (0 until clipData.itemCount).map { clipData.getItemAt(it).uri }.toTypedArray()
          } else {
            WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(result.resultCode, data)
          }

        cb.onReceiveValue(returnedValue)
      }
    }

inner class ChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onShowFileChooser(
      webView: WebView,
      filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
      fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams
    ): Boolean {
      Log.i("info", "CALLED ONSHOWFILECHOOSER")
      fileCallback = filePathCallback
      fileSelectorCallback.launch(fileChooserParams.createIntent())
      return true
    }
  }
```

Has anybody run into this issue? Do you know why it might be happening? And if so how did you fix it?

As I've kept above, I tried to log the ActivityResult after choosing a file. I expected to see properly returned data from the ActivityResult, but it simply says the file chooser activity was cancelled, even if I properly selected an image. I can repro this in the simulator and there are also user reports from people on Android 14.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that I was using

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in my manifest for the activity I was launching. Apparently this cancels all ActivityResults using the WebChromeClient on Android 14.